# Symfony2 - Invalid parameter number

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this error:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens

When I'm trying to get **getAllOrders()** in my Repository:

```
public function allOrdersQB()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->andWhere('o.state != :canceled')
        ->andWhere('o.state != :receipt_complete')
        ->setParameters(array(
        'receipt_complete' => 'receipt_complete',
        'canceled' => 'canceled',
    ));
}

public function getAllOrders()
{
    return $this->allOrdersQB()
        ->andWhere('o.stateCorp = :stateCorp')
        ->setParameters(array(
            'stateCorp' => 0,
        ))
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

I don't understand because I have set all the parameters.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setParameters` method reset all previous parameters, so you could use the simple `setParameter` call (see in the source code [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L592)), as example:

```
public function allOrdersQB()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->andWhere('o.state != :canceled')
        ->andWhere('o.state != :receipt_complete')
        ->setParameter('receipt_complete', 'receipt_complete')
        ->setParameter('canceled', 'canceled')
}

public function getAllOrders()
{
    return $this->allOrdersQB()
        ->andWhere('o.stateCorp = :stateCorp')
        ->setParameter('stateCorp', 0)
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: remove `:` in `setParameter()` function. Only `setParameter('canceled', 'canceled')`

Comment: It's ok with setPameter, I just had to resolve the same problem in another method